# Qt QWheelEvent angleDelta not changing

Tags: qt

I'm trying to implement a zoom feature in my program when the mouse scroll wheel moves. The code seems to work, except it zooms in whether I scroll the wheel up or down.

I debug print the wheel's angleDelta and it is some constant, huge number. I couldn't find anyone online which has had the same issue.

```
bool MyClass::eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event)
{
    QWheelEvent* wheel_event = static_cast<QWheelEvent*>(event);
    switch (static_cast<int>(event->type()))
    {
    case QEvent::GraphicsSceneWheel:
    {
        if (QApplication::keyboardModifiers() & Qt::ControlModifier)
        {
            const QGraphicsView::ViewportAnchor anchor = view->transformationAnchor();
            view->setTransformationAnchor(QGraphicsView::AnchorUnderMouse);
            int angle = wheel_event->angleDelta().y();
            qreal factor;

            qDebug() << "Ctrl + Wheel Event! Angle = " << angle << wheel_event->angleDelta().y() << wheel_event->pixelDelta().y() << wheel_event->delta() << wheel_event->angleDelta();

            if (angle > 0)
            {
                factor = 1.1;
            } else
            {
                factor = 0.9;
            }
            view->scale(factor, factor);
            view->setTransformationAnchor(anchor);
            break;
        }
    }
    }
}
```

I'd expect to see negative numbers when scrolling down, but all values I print never change regardless of the scroll direction. In this code, view is a pointer to a QGraphicsView object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `event->type() == QEvent::GraphicsSceneWheel` then the actual event type is [`QGraphicsSceneWheelEvent`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsscenewheelevent.html) *not* `QWheelEvent`.  So your code as shown has undefined behaviour.  Try (untested)...

```
bool MyClass::eventFilter (QObject *obj, QEvent *event)
{
    if (event->type() == QEvent::GraphicsSceneWheel) {
        if (auto *wheel_event = static_cast<QGraphicsSceneWheelEvent*>(event)) {
            if (QApplication::keyboardModifiers() & Qt::ControlModifier) {
                const QGraphicsView::ViewportAnchor anchor = view->transformationAnchor();
                view->setTransformationAnchor(QGraphicsView::AnchorUnderMouse);
                qreal factor;

                qDebug() << "Ctrl + Wheel Event! Delta = " << wheel_event->delta();

                if (wheel_event->delta() > 0) {
                    factor = 1.1;
                } else {
                    factor = 0.9;
                }
                view->scale(factor, factor);
                view->setTransformationAnchor(anchor);
            }
        }
    }

    /*
     * The following assumes `QObject` is the base class of MyClass.
     */
    return QObject::eventFilter(obj, event);
}
```

Comment: You got it, thanks! I cast my event as a QGraphicsSceneWheelEvent, and checked delta() instead of angleDelta(), and got the expected result of +/- 120. Would still like to understand the difference between a QWheelEvent vs QGraphicsSceneWheel event, but at least I can move on now.